# Is there any benefit from explicitly defining all used classes and namespaces at the beginning of PHP class?

Tags: php, oop

Consider these two classes:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

use LogicException;
use Memcached;

class Baz extends Memcached
{
    public function testBaz()
    {
        throw new LogicException('Not implemented');
    }
}
```

The same class could be written as:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

class Baz2 extends \Memcached
{
    public function testBaz()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('Not implemented');
    }
}
```

Is there any diffrence in performance of these two classes? What if we use Composer's optimized autoloading?

Also consider these two classes:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

use Acme\Demo;

class Kaz
{
    public function init(Demo\UnitA $unitA, Demo\UnitB $unitB)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The same could be coded as:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

use Acme\Demo\UnitA;
use Acme\Demo\UnitB;

class Kaz2
{
    public function init(UnitA $unitA, UnitB $unitB)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And again the same questions: is there any performance diffrence between those two? What if we use Composers optimized autoloading?

### To clarify the questions: is there any performance change?

I know what use is for, how to alias class names etc. I just wondered iof there is any performance hit useing one/or the other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[use operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) imports an external fully qualified name or gives it an alias in your namespace. Classes are loaded when you use them, not on import. So it will not make any difference on autoloading.

But using shorter class names in the code is a benefit, use it whenever you want.

**Update**

Importing is performed at compile-time so there should not be any difference in performance if you are using any kind of opcode cache like APC or OPcache (even if you are not using any it should be really insignificant change to not use the `use operator`).

Btw if you have concerns about the performance of your code the best thing is to use profilers. There are many of them like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), [blackfire](https://blackfire.io/). I personally prefer to use [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php).

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit: you don't have to write as much.
With simple cases like

```
use \classname;
```

that is just a backslash, but with more nested namespaces it can be a real timesaver

```
use \framework\section\library\someotherclass;
```

also, you can mock classes, change a used class without having to change it through the whole code, or use one class twice with different names:

```
use \framework\section\library\fakeclass as realclass;
```

more information: [php namespace importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: I've added a clarification: I'm only concerned about performance. Is there any diffrence?

Comment: I don't know, but I do not think so. And if there were, then most probably only under extremely exotic conditions and with extremely neglectable difference (e.g. precompiler-caching deactivated and so long paths that files grow enormously by not using use-as)